# Extracting Function or Objects from a String and then Piping Them with Magrittr/Dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I am trying to write some code in which a given string can be read as a function or object and then subsequently piped. I thought eval(parse()) would be the most natural choice, but with at least with certain functions, it fails to read the string appropriately in combination with the pipe. For instance, say I have two strings with an expression and number I want to pipe:

```
 first <- "1"
 second <- "seq(10,2)"
```

The output should be identical to what you would get when you pipe:
      `1 %>% seq(10,2)`
Or
      `seq(1,10,2)`

Instead, I get the error,

> Error in eval(., parse(text = second)) : 
>     invalid 'envir' argument of type 'expression', when I try to do the following:

```
  eval(parse(first)) %>%
      eval(parse(second))
```

When I try to assign them to named objects first and then pipe them, I get an error saying that the second object is not found:

```
  the.ex <- eval(parse(first))
  that.ex <- eval(parse(second))

   the.ex %>%
       that.ex
```

When I try it with various other expressions/objects, sometimes it works (like with `lm(cars) - cars%>%lm`), but in most instances I get similar errors to the above. How could I go about doing this so that it works for a wide variety of expressions/objects that could be pulled out of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me warn you that storing code as strings is generally not a very safe thing to do and we try to avoid it.

The reason your methods don't work is that you are piping into the `eval()` the function, not the results of the eval function. And plus you want to delay the evaluation of the second term until the data has been piped in.

You are going to need to build the complete piped expression before evaulating it. One way to do that with base R is the `bquote()` function. For example

```
library(matrittr)
eval(bquote(.(parse(text=first)[[1]]) %>% .(parse(text=second)[[1]])))
# [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Removing the `eval()`, you can see that it first build the expression you are after

```
bquote(.(parse(text=first)[[1]]) %>% .(parse(text=second)[[1]]))
# 1 %>% seq(10, 2)
```

With `rlang`, you might do something like this

```
library(rlang)
eval_tidy(expr(!!parse_expr(first) %>% !!parse_expr(second)))
```

Again you just need to be sure to build the complete expression first.

A more generic solution to join expressions with an operator might look something like this

```
join_exprs <- function(exprs, op=`+`) {
  op <- ensym(op)
  N <- length(exprs)
  new_call <- exprs[[1]]
  for(x in exprs[-1]) {
    new_call <- expr((!!op)(!!new_call,!!x))
  }
  new_call
}

join_exprs(parse_exprs(c(first, second)), `%>%`)
# 1 %>% seq(10, 2)
```

This would scale to any number of expressions

```
join_exprs(parse_exprs(c("5", "exp", "round(2)")), `%>%`)
# 5 %>% exp %>% round(2)
```

And you can evaulate them with `eval()`.

Comment: Yes! That seems to work perfectly for what I was needing - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve this one. At the moment I can do:

```
first <- "1"
second <- "seq(10,2)"

>eval(parse(text = first))
[1] 1 #output

eval(parse(text = second))
[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2 #output
```

But I cannot pipe them together. I suspect this is because the result isn't piped to the correct place:

```
parse(text = second)
expression(seq(10,2)) #output
```

You want it to do this behind the scences:

```
expression(seq(., 10, 2)) #the . is the piped result
```

But is actually does this:

```
expression(., seq(10,2))
```

since the output is always piped to the place of the first variable unless otherwise specified.

I hope someone else can help you with this problem.